# JavaMail api: error on copyMessages

Tags: jakarta-mail

We are using javamail-1.4.5-mailapi.jar to copy messages from a folder to another:

**_folder.copyMessages(new Message[] { getMail().getMessage() }, destination);**

Where getMail().getMessage() returns a MimeMessage,

This function used to work a long time ago (maybe with older version of javamail jars), but recently it is throwing this error:

**javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be cast to com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPMessage**

Does anyone know what is causing this issue?

Thank you,

Karine

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across a very closely related issue myself. I had to set a header on a message and then copy it to a folder, which meant I had to create a MimeMessage copy of an IMAPMessage and then set the header and then copy it. What I did, and I have to admit it's counter-intuitive, was to cast the folder to an IMapFolder:

```
((IMAPFolder)_folder).copyMessages(new Message[] { getMail().getMessage() }, destination);
```

should work for you. Still this should not be necessary, but this seems a fairly safe workaround.